# state transfer in FSM, written in verilog

Tags: verilog

The code :

```
module demux(   input clk, rst_n, NewPacket,
    input [7:0] DataIn,
    output reg[7:0] Dataout0,Dataout1,Dataout2,Dataout3,Dataout4,Dataout5,Dataout6,Dataout7);

reg[1:0] state, state_n;
reg[7:0] Data_temp1;
reg[3:0] packet_size;
reg[2:0] outport;

parameter   S0 = 2'd0,
            S1 = 2'd1,
            S2 = 2'd2;

always @(posedge clk)
if(!rst_n)
    state <= S0;
else begin
    state <= state_n;
    Data_temp1 <= DataIn;
    if(packet_size > 0)begin
        packet_size <= packet_size - 1;
        outport <= outport + 1;
    end
end

always @(state, NewPacket, packet_size) begin
state_n = 2'bx;
case(state)
    S0: if(NewPacket)
            state_n = S1;
        else
            state_n = S0;
    S1: begin
            packet_size = Data_temp1[3:0];
            outport = Data_temp1[6:4] - 1;
            state_n = S2;
        end
    S2: if(packet_size > 0)
            state_n = S2;
        else
            state_n = S0;
endcase
end

always @(posedge clk)
if(!rst_n)
    {Dataout0,Dataout1,Dataout2,Dataout3,Dataout4,Dataout5,Dataout6,Dataout7} <= 64'b0;
else begin
    {Dataout0,Dataout1,Dataout2,Dataout3,Dataout4,Dataout5,Dataout6,Dataout7} <= 64'b0;
    if(state == S2)
        case(outport)
        0:  Dataout0 <= Data_temp1;
        1:  Dataout1 <= Data_temp1;
        2:  Dataout2 <= Data_temp1;
        3:  Dataout3 <= Data_temp1;
        4:  Dataout4 <= Data_temp1;
        5:  Dataout5 <= Data_temp1;
        6:  Dataout6 <= Data_temp1;
        7:  Dataout7 <= Data_temp1;
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

The testbench:

```
    `timescale 1ns / 1ps

module demux_tb;

// Inputs
reg clk;
reg rst_n;
reg NewPacket;
reg [7:0] DataIn;

// Outputs
wire [7:0] Dataout0;
wire [7:0] Dataout1;
wire [7:0] Dataout2;
wire [7:0] Dataout3;
wire [7:0] Dataout4;
wire [7:0] Dataout5;
wire [7:0] Dataout6;
wire [7:0] Dataout7;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
demux uut (
    .clk(clk), 
    .rst_n(rst_n), 
    .NewPacket(NewPacket), 
    .DataIn(DataIn), 
    .Dataout0(Dataout0), 
    .Dataout1(Dataout1), 
    .Dataout2(Dataout2), 
    .Dataout3(Dataout3), 
    .Dataout4(Dataout4), 
    .Dataout5(Dataout5), 
    .Dataout6(Dataout6), 
    .Dataout7(Dataout7)
);

initial
    forever #10 clk <= ~clk;

initial
begin
    clk = 1;
    rst_n = 1;
    NewPacket = 0;
    DataIn = 0;

    #20 rst_n = 0;
        #60 rst_n = 1;

    #20 DataIn = 8'h73;
    NewPacket = 1;

    #20 DataIn = 8'h11;
    NewPacket = 0;

    #20 DataIn = 8'h22;

    #20 DataIn = 8'h33;

    #20 DataIn = 8'h44;

    #20 DataIn = 8'b0;

    #20 DataIn = 8'h02;
    NewPacket = 1;

    #20 DataIn = 8'h88;
    NewPacket = 0;

    #20 DataIn = 8'h99; 
end

endmodule
```

The waveform:
[image]

In my mind, state_n should change to 1 first and the next clk state change to 1 and state_n change to 2. But in waveform, state_n change to 2 from 0 directly, Why ?

Comment: I see a possible race condition in the scheduler in the testbench. Clock should be blocking (`clk = ~clk`), everything after `#20` should be non-blocking (`<=`). In `demux`, `Data_temp1`, and `packet_size` should have a reset value in the `if(!rst_n)` block, and `@(state, NewPacket, packet_size)` should be changed to `@*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is race condition in the testbench. `NewPacket` is updated and triggers an update to `state_n` all before the clock is ever updated. This all happens within the same time step. To help visualize this race, change the time of the first `#20` to `#19` or `#21`.

The testbench should use non-blocking assignments to all signals going to the `uut`; except `clk`. Clocks should have blocking assignments.

```
initial
    forever #10 clk = ~clk; // Blocking

initial
begin
    // blocking is okay here for initialization
    clk = 1;
    rst_n = 1;
    NewPacket = 0;
    DataIn = 0;

    // From here on, use non-blocking assignments to signals going to uut
    #20 rst_n <= 0;
    #60 rst_n <= 1;

    #20 DataIn <= 8'h73;
    NewPacket <= 1;

    ...

    #20 $finish; // tell the simulator to end
end
```

Working example [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/CeU)

---

Suggestions to improve `demux`:

- `Data_temp1`, `packet_size`, and `outport` should have a reset value in the `if(!rst_n)` block.
- `packet_size` and `outport` are also assigned in two always blocks which is illegal for synthesis. For synthesizable code, a variable should only be assigned in only one `always` block. Creating two new variables for calculating the next values; like the `state_n`-`state` relation. FYI: `*_n` is often a coding style for active low. `*_next`, `next_*`, or `*_ns` are more common prefixes/suffixes for next calculations.
- It is recommended to use `@*` or `@(*)` for combinational logic blocks instead of specifying signals in the sensitivity list. Therefore, replace `@(state, NewPacket, packet_size)` with `@*`

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with TL-Verilog (http://www.tl-x.org), and I was looking for an example to code up.  I happened to grab this one and ran with it today.  The results look really nice.  Thought I'd share.

There's a learning curve w/ TL-Verilog syntax, but all the issues w/ blocking/non-blocking, sensitivity lists and the like that were gotchas in this post are gone.  So my answer to your post is, "use TL-Verilog".

I coded it up here: http://sandpiper.edaplayground.com/x/EHd.  You should be able to compile and simulate it yourself, play w/ it, and debug w/ waveforms.  I think it is crazy cool that it came out to be half the size!

Here's my version of the "demux" code, translated from the code above:

```
    \TLV_version 0.1: http://TBD
    \SV
    module demux_TLV(   input clk, rst_n, NewPacket,
        input [7:0] DataIn,
        output reg[7:0] Dataout[7:0]);

    \TLV
       |pipe
          @0
             // Inputs
    !        $new_packet = *NewPacket;
    !        $data_in[7:0] = *DataIn;

          @1
             // Logic
             $done_packet = $packet_size == 0;
    !        {$outport[2:0], $packet_size[3:0]} =
                !*rst_n          ? '0 :
                !$done_packet#+1 ? {$outport#+1 + 3'b1,   $packet_size#+1 - 4'b1} :
                $new_packet      ? {$data_in[6:4] - 3'b1, $data_in[3:0]} :
                                   {$outport#+1,          $packet_size#+1};

          @2
             // Output
             >port[7:0]
    !           $data_out[7:0] = (*rst_n &&
                                  !|pipe$done_packet#+1 &&
                                  (port == |pipe$outport)) ? |pipe$data_in
                                                           : '0;
                *Dataout[port] = $data_out;

    \SV

    endmodule
```

It's not a direct translation.  More of a logic rewrite.

The EDA Playground code has the original and my version, both instantiated from the testbench.  They produce the same output in simulation.

I realize I'm running the risk of starting a discussion in this thread.  Please don't go there; that's not my intent.  I just wanted to post another potential solution.

Thanks for the fun example to play with!